# How to make clicking a bookmark in Firefox replace current tab (not open new tab)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I usually use Chrome, and clicking a bookmark would change the URL in the current tab.  But in Firefox 57, clicking a bookmark always opens a new tab. I don't like this behavior, how can I make it work similar to Chrome?

[image]

Comment: *"But in FF57, click bookmark always open a new tab in most right."*  How are you accessing your bookmarks?  When I select one, it always opens within the current tab... just like you want.

Comment: @Run5k update gif . Here I install a plugin to make new tab open right to current. Default behavious is open in most right.

Comment: The default behavior **should** be to open a bookmark within the current tab.  Unless somebody (or something) modified the `about:config` settings in your Firefox profile as described in this article:  [How to set Firefox to automatically open a new tab by left clicking a link or when opening a bookmark?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1191501)

Comment: @Run5k You are right, it is by a plugin http://mozilla.com.cn/thread-319507-1-1.html , which be bundled in Firefox installer chinese edition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by this http://mozilla.com.cn/thread-319507-1-1.html

I downloaded firefox on mozilla.com.cn , and this plugin is the default plugin in the installer. Disable it solve the problem.